# Как сделать аутентификацию в asp core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

У меня аутентификация на стороне сервера сделана:

```
var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(inputModel.Email, inputModel.Password, inputModel.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: true);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
            return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
        }
```

И в startup

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultForbidScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultSignOutScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        });
```

На стороне сервера у меня нормально заходит (result.Succeeded=true),
Но на стороне клиента не определяет, что пользователь авторизован:
На стороне сервера:

```
@if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
```

Comment: Куки выставить забыли. Вы теорию читали? Примеры пробовали?  [`Аутентификация и авторизация`](https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/15.1.php)

Comment: @tym32167, Сейчас начну читать. Просто были выставлены стандартная авторизация при создании проекта. Но потом что-то съехало и не могу восстановить стандартные  настройки.

Comment: так создайте ещё одно приложение со стандартной авторизацией, какие проблемы?

Comment: @tym32167, в том что данное мне кажется легче сделать, чем по новой делать. Мне нужно чтобы авторизация была на главной странице. Я не очень понял как это нормально сделать. Т.к. передается какой то индекс

Comment: вам не надо по новой делать, вам надо сделать второй проект и скопипастить оттуда авторизацию в свой проект. Вы дольше рассуждаете, не надо слов, просто пробуйте

Comment: @tym32167, Там вообще отсутствует AddAuthentication и AddAuthentication. Но авторизация работает, когда я так убираю в текущем проекте, то пишет ошибку

Comment: Меня одного смущает, что `options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme` тогда как все остальные `= CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme`? Может оно так и надо, просто с документацией по данной теме беда.